# Get List ordered by number of records from another table using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm using EF6 and I created this two models:

```
public class Publication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ViewLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User.User User { get; set; }
    public int? SessionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SessionId")]
    public User.Session Session { get; set; }
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PublicationId")]
    public Publication.Publication Publication { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Every time I visit a Publication I create a new record into ViewLog table.
Now, using Linq, I need to get all Publications ordered by the number of ViewLogs (visits) per publication in the last 24hs. (If Publication has no ViewLogs they need to appear too, but obviously after the publications that has viewlogs)

Comment: Did you try anything ? You can try doing `Left Join` with `Group BY` with `Having Count`.

Comment: Yes, I know how to get this with SQL, but I can't find something similar in Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupJoin` when you don't have navigation properties and need a left outer join

The lambda syntax goes like this:

```
var publicationQuery = new List<Publication>().AsQueryable();
var viewLogQuery = new List<ViewLog>().AsQueryable();

var leftJoinQuery = publicationQuery
    .GroupJoin(viewLogQuery, x => x.Id, x => x.PublicationId, (pub, logs) => new
    {
        PublicationId = pub.Id,
        LogCount = logs.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LogCount);
```

I also found this [Query Expression Translation Cheat Sheet](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx) very useful to go from query expressions (which are closer to SQL) to lambda method syntax (which I prefer)

If you do have a navigation property `Publication.ViewLogs` (which is a `List<ViewLog>`), then you can just use `Select()` with a projection

```
var publicationQuery = new List<Publication>().AsQueryable(); // From a DbSet...

var query = publicationQuery
    .Select(x => new
    {
        PublicationId = x.Id,
        LogCount = x.ViewLogs.Count
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LogCount);
```

Comment: Andrés, if I create a navigation property, for example creating a List of ViewLogs in Publications, that's easier? (I have already the Publication Id into ViewLog). Could you please post an example of that situation too? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Updated my answer... not sure if you have any other requirements that are not reflected in the question...